# PyQt5: QSlider valueChanged event with delay

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qslider

I'm using QSlider in my GUI application in order to perform a heavy task after value changed in the QSlider. I'm doing that as follows.

```
self.slider.valueChanged.connect(self.value_changed)  # Inside __init__() function

def value_changed(self):  # Inside the class
    # Do the heavy task
```

But I can't change the value of the slider smoothly because the heavy task is running every time I change the value.

What I need is to run the heavy task after the value changed but only if the value of the slider is not changing for a while.

I can't figure out how to  do this in python. Any help..?

Comment: You can explain better, maybe you need to use QThread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `startTimer/killTimer` to delay your task:

```
class Foo(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.timer_id = -1
        self.slider = QSlider(self)
        self.slider.setMinimum(0)
        self.slider.setMaximum(100)
        self.slider.valueChanged.connect(self.value_changed)

    def timerEvent(self, event):
        self.killTimer(self.timer_id)
        self.timer_id = -1
        heavy_task()

    def value_changed(self):
        if self.timer_id != -1:
            self.killTimer(self.timer_id)

        self.timer_id = self.startTimer(3000)
```

so, as can you see we restart timer every time when
user something change, so if 3000 millseconds not expires
since last change `heavy_task` not run,

but any way it will be running in main thread, so for some
time interface freeze for user, so you should use
`QThread` in `timerEvent` to not have interface that not freeze during
`heavy_task` execution.

Answer (score 4):

I am no expert, and I arrive long after the battle, but i needed a thing like that too, and i don't understand a thing about the timers. It worked fine for one slider, but i needed 3. So I came up with this solution : when the slider is pressed, I disconnect the valueChanged slot, and when the slider is released, I reconnect it and I throw a valueChanged signal, like this :

```
    self.sldAZap.valueChanged.connect(self.sliderChanged)
    self.sldAZap.sliderPressed.connect(self.sldDisconnect)
    self.sldAZap.sliderReleased.connect(self.sldReconnect)

def sldDisconnect(self):
    self.sender().valueChanged.disconnect()

def sldReconnect(self):
    self.sender().valueChanged.connect(self.sliderChanged)
    self.sender().valueChanged.emit(self.sender().value())

def sliderChanged(self):
    print(self.sender().objectName() + " : " + str(self.sender().value())
```

With this solution, there is no delay between the moment the mouse is released and the execution of the code, and the code is executed just one time.

I hope I am clear enough and it may help someone.